# secret or public key must be provided - IOS/Swift + Socket.io-JWT

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, jwt

My goal is very simple, authenticate a user via socket.io jwt. So that I could manipulate his/her data in real-time.

Clientside code

```
import SocketIOClientSwift
import KeychainAccess

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    // 1
    let keychain = Keychain(server: "https://testing.herokuapp.com", protocolType: .HTTPS)

    //2
    var token: String {
        get {
            if let realToken = keychain["token"] {
                return String(realToken)
            } else {
                return ""
            }

        }
    }

    //3
    lazy var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "https://testing.herokuapp.com")!,
                                                     options: [.Log(true), .ConnectParams(["token": self.token])])

    override init() {
        super.init()

    }


    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
    }

    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }



}
```

Just for you guys to understand

1. keychain purpose is just to store the token, let say I already saved
   the token from user who logs in, then I will simply do this
   `keychain["token"] = "token"`, lets assume that the token has been
   saved
2. `var token` is to get the token, because currently keychain store
   the token in optional, thus i need to do optional binding.
3. Lastly I instantiate a socket object, so that I could pass the token
   as the parameter, many people recommend to do this
   `.ConnectParams(["token": self.token])`

So far so good, but right now, whenever I try to establish a connection in an app delegate ,

**AppDelegate.Swift**

```
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
    }
```

I will received

```
Handling event: error with data: (
        {
        code = "invalid_token";
        message = "secret or public key must be provided";
        type = UnauthorizedError;
    } )
```

For clarity, I don't want to include the serverside code because It's just a boilerplate code from this https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt

So, the real question is, what did I do wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't provide a secret in your server implementation:

`socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: 'some secret here',  // <--
  handshake: true
})`

Comment: I have one more question for you if i received `socket: [object Object]`, how would I get the data? like first_name and so on. Because whenever Im trying to console.log `socket.decoded_token.first_name` it shows `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

inside your .env add JWT_SECRET=JWT_SECRET

Comment: This requires having something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) installed, and even then it just sets it as an environment variable, you'd still need to set it explicitly using `process.env.JWT_SECRET` as @Wilson noted.